# How can I install lxml in docker

Tags: python, docker, lxml, dockerfile

I want to deploy my python project in docker, I wrote `lxml>=3.5.0` in the requirments.txt as the project needs lxml. Here is my dockfile:

```
FROM gliderlabs/alpine:3.3
RUN set -x \
    && buildDeps='\
        python-dev \
        py-pip \
        build-base \
    ' \
    && apk --update add python py-lxml $buildDeps \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && mkdir -p /app
ENV INSTALL_PATH /app
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH
COPY requirements-docker.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN apk del --purge $buildDeps
ENTRYPOINT ["celery", "-A", "tasks", "worker", "-l", "info", "-B"]
```

I got this when I deploy it to docker:

```
*********************************************************************************
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
*********************************************************************************
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
Rolling back uninstall of lxml
```

I though it was because 'python-dev' and 'python-lxml', then I edited the dockfile like this:

```
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH
COPY requirements-docker.txt ./
RUN apt-get build-dev python-lxml
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It did not work, and I got another error:

```
---> Running in 73201a0dcd59
/bin/sh: apt-get: not found
```

How can I install lxml correctly in docker?

Comment: You use alpine, so it may be `apk add` but not `apt-get`

Comment: @user2915097  Thanks! I changed it to `apk add python-dev py-lxml`, it returned the error: `error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`. I don't know how to install lxml

Comment: the package name is correct https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/main/x86/py-lxml

Comment: seems to install lxml fine in this Dockerfile https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/main/x86/py-lxml or https://hub.docker.com/r/ryanfox1985/docker-couchpotato/builds/boinrrs9dbhnutwjxjw2l8m/ or https://hub.docker.com/r/trcook/docker-scrapy/builds/bfrzq6d6nzquxl5vw3qt4k5/

Answer (score 82):

I added `RUN apk add --update --no-cache g++ gcc libxslt-dev` before `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` and it worked.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the release version of libxslt-dev is not necessary, you can do `libxslt-dev`.

Comment: I don't think that g++ is required for building libxml2 so I think that you can replace g++ with libc-dev which results in a smaller container for me.

Comment: Here's a full working Dockerfile for lxml on alpine https://gist.github.com/deliro/509b663093ff0f49c1b71e1876597ccb

Comment: Why have you used --no-cache?? I guess we don't want to increase image size if it is so, can we cache it with Docker?

Comment: @SeasonedNoob Actually we do not want to cache anything as the build dependencies are getting removed anyway.

Comment: gcc is also not needed as it is part of g++

Answer (score 21):

Accepted answer is not neat and installs redundant packages. Better solution for reducing image size will be:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc libc-dev libxslt-dev && \
    apk add --no-cache libxslt && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir lxml>=3.5.0 && \
    apk del .build-deps
```

Result image size will be < **163MB**

Comment: thanks @bohdan-sukhov
In my testing I've found you will also need to add the package `py3-lxml` in order for it to work

Comment: rather than bothering to delete .build-deps, you can use [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/),  with

///    # install dependencies
///    COPY ./requirements.txt .
///    RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt
///
in the first build, and

///    COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
///    COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .

///    RUN pip install --upgrade --no-cache pip
///    RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*
///
in the final build.

Comment: From 274MB to 63MB :D Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Since I was using a much more bare-bone image I needed some more libs/apps.

This worked for me:

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache g++ gcc libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev make

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

[Since only this answer worked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60167882/15122944) for me and I wanted something light

[And I liked this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57535436/15122944), but which didn't work for me at first

I've edited it for myself and got this at the end :

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .build-deps g++ gcc libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev && \
    apk add --no-cache libxslt && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir lxml>=3.5.0 && \
    apk del .build-deps
```

The final image is around 110MB, and didn't have anymore any libxml and libslt errors

Answer (score -2):

Do as in

https://hub.docker.com/r/ryanfox1985/docker-couchpotato/builds/boinrrs9dbhnutwjxjw2l8m/

Download the apk and install it

`RUN wget http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/x86_64/py-lxml-3.4.0-r0.apk -O /var/cache/apk/py-lxml.apk
RUN apk add --allow-untrusted /var/cache/apk/py-lxml.apk`

Comment: Just out of curiosity why was this downvoted so hard?

Comment: @digitaldavenyc I didn't downvote; however, downloading an unauthenticated package and installing that as part of the build process _does_ sound horrible to me.

Answer (score -6):

Actually, it's just

```
RUN apt-get install -y libxslt1-dev
```

Comment: They are using  alpine (aka no apt)